# regex validating url

Tags: php, regex

I have the following urls as subjects

```
localhost/hx
localhost/h.php
localhost/h/x
localhost/h/x/y
localhsot/h?hello
localhost/h
```

Currently my pattern is something like `/localhost/h[/]*/i`, but this does not work.

I do not want to match line 1 or 2, but the others are valid.

- Problem 1: I am not able to make `/` or `?` optional, if I remove `*` from the pattern it does not match `localhost/h`.
- Problem 2: I am not able to escape `?` for line 5, I tried `\\` and `\` but neither worked.

Comment: Why should lines 1 and 2 not be matched while the following should? What are the rules you need to follow?

Comment: As a side note, the strings you provided as input are not [`URL`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax). They are some strings that happens to be presented as "locations" by the web browsers in an attempt to simplify the UI.

Comment: Those are not valid URLs, and that is not a valid regex (in most systems).  Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31023286/edit) in accordance with the suggestions in the [`regex` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).  Thanks.

Comment: this kind of urls matching I need for htaccess url test tool , and using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
/localhost\/h(?:\/|\?|$)/
```

Comment: This would also match `localhost/h/` and `localhost/h?` which may not be desirable in their meaning on a web request. (Not a criticism, just though this worth being noted)

Answer (score 1):

You have two conditions:

- The uri should end up after the `h`
- The uri should be `h` followed by `/` or `?` and some chars after

so you need an alternative match.

a correct regex would be `localhost\/h(?:$|[?\/].+)` [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/cB4uE1/1)

What is does is matching `localhost/h` litteraly and then opening a non capturing group `(?:` with two alternative

- end of line with `$`

or `|`

- `/` or `?` followed by at least one char `.+`

Answer (score 1):

I used a regex making use of [Negative Lookbehinds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

**Regex**: `.*+(?<!\.php)(?<!hx)`

See this [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rC9lA6/1) too see how it works.